# Destroying and re-creating the current object from a member function, within an inheritance hierarchy

Tags: c++, memory, language-lawyer, c++20, undefined-behavior

Consider the following example from [[basic.life#8]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#8) in the standard (this is the relevant part of it):

```
const C& C::operator=( const C& other) {
  if ( this != &other ) {
    this->~C();
    new (this) C(other);
  }
  return *this;
}
```

This is simple enough, but I started to wonder what happens when the class is part of an inheritance hierarchy.
Let's look at the following:

```
struct Base {
    void base_replace() {
        this->~Base();
        new (this) Base();
    }

    int base_member;
};

struct Derived: Base { };
```

Does the following code introduce undefined behaviour?

```
Derived derived;
derived.base_replace();
derived.base_member = 5;
```

My first thought was that calling `replace_base()` would end the lifetime of `derived`, because *"a program may end the lifetime of any object by reusing the storage which the object occupies [...]"* ([[basic.life#5]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#5)). Since the base class sub-object is nested within the storage occupied by `derived`, calling `base_replace()` would re-use (part of) the storage of `derived`, thus ending its lifetime (instead of only ending the lifetime of the base class sub-object).
However, that does not seem to be the case, because [[basic.life.1.5]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#1.5) specifies that this rule does not apply to nested sub-objects. So the lifetime of `derived` does not seem to end here.

But even if `derived`'s lifetime is not affected in any way, can it still be used after the call to `base_replace()`? The problem here is that the base class sub-object of `derived` is not transparently-replaceable, due to being a *"potentially-overlapping subobject"* ([[basic.life#8.4]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#8.4), [[intro.object#7.1]](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#7.1)).
This could mean that after this operation, I'd have to use `std::launder` to access the base class sub-object. But if I access the base class sub-object of `derived` **through an object of type `Derived`** (such as with `derived.base_member = 5;`), does this actually count as accessing the base class sub-object of `derived`, or just the `derived` object?
If it does count as accessing the base class sub-object, my guess is that I would have to replace the line:

```
derived.base_member = 5;
```

with either

```
std::launder(&derived)->base_member = 5;
```

or

```
std::launder(static_cast<Base*>(&derived))->base_member = 5;
```

I don't know which of the above is the correct choice. It's also extremely likely that my logic is incorrect somewhere along the way, but that's why I'm asking this question. I hope I at least managed to describe the problem clearly.

Comment: The newly-created object of `Base` type is not nested within `derived` because only member subobjects and array elements can be replaced, see [[intro.object\]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/intro.object#2). Thus, the newly-created `Base` object ends the lifetime of `derived` by reusing its storage (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.life#1.5)

Comment: Rule of zero/rule of five should also apply here, If the derived is implementing a virtual destructor they probably implement a virtual assignment operator too...

Comment: What is your goal here? Do you intend to replace the full Derived object with a `Base` one or only replace the Base part of a Derived object? In the first case, the destructor should be virtual but the replaced object is only a Base one, and accessing any attribute of Derived will be UB, in the second one, you should use containment and not derivation.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Does that mean that when I first create an object `derived` of type `Derived`, the `Base` part of it **is** its sub-object, but when I create another `Base` object in its storage, it will not become a sub-object of `derived` and instead becomes a complete object (thus ending the lifetime of `derived`)?

Comment: Yes. Because a base-class subobject can haz a different layout (than a complete object of the same type) and also vtable, so it is not easy to efficiently replace it not affecting the containing object. AFAIR there already is an answer explaining this.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Thank you for the explanation, this answers the whole question.